# how do you update to the latest branch without having to download everything again?

Tags: android, git, android-source

To use the latest manifest you do:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

But if you want to download a specific branch (such as android 4.0.1) you do:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.1_r1
```

- Now say I want to update to the latest (nougat), what should I do ?
- Do I need to create a new repo ?
- Will I have to download everything all over again ?
- Or is there a way to just download the remaining (from 4.0.1 to latest) ?

Comment: You have to download everything all over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the `$repo init` to the branch and manifest you want (Nougat) in the same root directory. If there are common commits, those will not be downloaded.

BUT, I doubt you will get the same HEAD recent enough as for the download not to take quite some time, and space.

Also, depending on your needs, you may want to try to pass `--depth=1`, to your `repo init` in order to get a shallow clone of the repositories. I have never tried it myself but theoretically, it should take less time/space, although you will be missing the whole history.